# Opening HTML form attachments in iOS5

Tags: email, ios5

I have received an email on my iPhone (with iOS 5.0.1) with an HTML attachment. The HTML attachment contains a form to fill out and submit. The problem is that submitting the form does not work. I click the Submit button and I get switched Safari, but the form information is not posted. Instead, the URL indicated by the form gets requested as via the GET method.

Is the problem that the Quick Look viewer is simply a passive viewer that does not do forms? I'd like to be able to open the attachment in Safari instead, but that does not appear to be an option. If a tap and hold the attachment, the only options I get are Quick Look and Dropbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I've decided it simply does not work. Probably by design as a sort of security feature. I discovered a similar problem with Android phones.